# How to find Camera resolution and aspect ratio in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to get supported camera resolution preview size and aspected ratio in list view like i have shown in the pictures. Currently i am doing this which only show me a list of resolution width and height but i also want to show aspect ration.

```
public void find_camera_resolution()
  {
    Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int widths[] = new int[params.getSupportedPreviewSizes().size()];
    int heights[] = new int[params.getSupportedPictureSizes().size()];

    Camera.Size mSize;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Available resolution: "+widths.length+" "+size.height,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mSize = size;
    }
}
```

But i want to show like this in the picture [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio is just the the ratio of the resolution. So you (just) need to find the [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of width and height, divide the both values by the divisior and then you got your ratio.

For example 1600x720 -> GCD: 80 -> 1600/80=20, 720/80=9 -> aspect ratio: 20:9

There are a lot of existing algorithms to solve the Createst Common Divisor Problem and there existist already some implementations which you can use.

***Sample source code are here:***

```
 int gcd=find_greatest_common_divisor_of_two_number(widths[i], heights[i]);
 String ratio =(widths[i]/gcd)+":"+(heights[i]/gcd);

 private static int find_greatest_common_divisor_of_two_number(int number1, int number2) {
    //base case
    if(number2 == 0){
        return number1;
    }
    return find_greatest_common_divisor_of_two_number(number2, number1%number2);
}
```